# Looking for elements in a set

Tags: python, set

I'm a little confused on which data structure to use to compare if an element matches another element in a set.

Lets say `user_input` asks the user to type in their name. if their name matches up they are granted access but this doesn't work.

```
access = set(['John', 'Jane', 'Jack', 'Janice'])

if (user_input == access):
    print ('Allow in!')
else:
    print ('Deny!')
```

Comment: You need to use `in` operand for check the membership! so change `user_input == access` to `user_input in access`

Comment: @Kasra, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `in` to check if something is a member

```
access = set(['John', 'Jane', 'Jack', 'Janice'])

if (user_input in access):
    print ('Allow in!')
else:
    print ('Deny!')
```